# How to order the parameters passed on a form_tag path?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, parameters

I'm passing some params trough the form_tag but it's not passing them as I want it, on the actual view I have `params[:id]` with `:id` being '225907' (a specific number) but after I execute the `form_tag`, it truncates that `params[:id]` and changes it to the name of the `action => params[:id]='save_path'`

Inside the `form_tag` it's stated a Cita (Meeting) with all the parameters it needs to save for a meeting, all of that is Ok as it is passed into a hash through the params path as an element, but there's another element called `Id` which should have a numeric value that identifies my users, then the `form_tag` passes it wrong:

Parameters:

> {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"bQu90nWiFQdn8GTwZH4xedyZiLhhTUCT5DjLUOqgfB2aiju3V7EFbRMI4LwLJNzIsVAOiryJ1+fHjfDCaP6thw==",
>   "cita"=>{"fecha"=>"2019/08/26", "requiere"=>"false",
>   "matricula"=>"214876", "cve_empleado"=>"91985", "id_centro"=>"",
>   "id_facultad"=>"", "tipo"=>"1", "area"=>"", "especialidad"=>"",
>   "experto"=>"", "tema"=>"9", "subtema"=>"92", "orientacion"=>"67",
>   "problema"=>"", "materia"=>"", "asesor"=>"", "nota"=>"fgnfhfgh",
>   "ciclo"=>"2370"}, "checkboxReq2"=>"on", "optionsCheckboxes2"=>"1",
>   "id"=>"save_path"}

Form:

```
 <%= form_tag(guardar_tutoria_path, method: :post) do |f| %>
        <input type="hidden" name="cita[fecha]" value="{{cita.fecha}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="cita[requiere]" value="{{cita.requiere}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="cita[matricula]" value="{{cita.matricula}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="cita[cve_empleado]" value="{{cita.cve_empleado}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="cita[id_centro]" value="{{cita.id_centro}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="cita[id_facultad]" value="{{cita.id_facultad}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="cita[tipo]" value="{{cita.tipo}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="cita[area]" value="{{cita.area}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="cita[especialidad]" value="{{cita.especialidad}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="cita[experto]" value="{{cita.experto}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="cita[tema]" value="{{cita.tema}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="cita[subtema]" value="{{cita.subtema}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="cita[orientacion]" value="{{cita.orientacion}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="cita[problema]" value="{{cita.problema}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="cita[materia]" value="{{cita.materia}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="cita[asesor]" value="{{cita.asesor}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="cita[nota]" value="{{cita.nota}}">
```

The expected result should have the `Id` with the user's Id not with the name of the action:

Parameters:

> {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"bQu90nWiFQdn8GTwZH4xedyZiLhhTUCT5DjLUOqgfB2aiju3V7EFbRMI4LwLJNzIsVAOiryJ1+fHjfDCaP6thw==",
>   "cita"=>{"fecha"=>"2019/08/26", "requiere"=>"false",
>   "matricula"=>"214876", "cve_empleado"=>"91985", "id_centro"=>"",
>   "id_facultad"=>"", "tipo"=>"1", "area"=>"", "especialidad"=>"",
>   "experto"=>"", "tema"=>"9", "subtema"=>"92", "orientacion"=>"67",
>   "problema"=>"", "materia"=>"", "asesor"=>"", "nota"=>"fgnfhfgh",
>   "ciclo"=>"2370"}, "checkboxReq2"=>"on", "optionsCheckboxes2"=>"1",
>   "id"=>"225907"}

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

On my route I added the Id to the path and all of it is working now:

post '/follow_up/save_meeting/:id', to: 'tutoring/follow_up#save_meeting', as: :save_meeting